# Selecting DataRow using Linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq, select, filter, where-clause

How can I make this to shorter one using Linq?

```
int id = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData())
{
     if (dr[0].ToString() == txtClientName.Text)
      {
          id = Convert.ToInt16(dr[1]);
          break;
      }
}
```

I tried using this

```
var a = tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData().Cast<DataRow>().Where(cName => cName[0].ToString() == txtClientName.Text);
MessageBox.Show(a[1].ToString());
```

But I got this error:

> Error 1   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection'   C:\Users\vrynxzent@yahoo.com\Desktop[Final][GlobalTek] Monitoring System[GlobalTek] Monitoring System\xfrmProjectAwarding.cs  89  37  [GlobalTek] Monitoring System

Any help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var a =` is a *sequence* of DataRow items that you are trying to treat as a single object. If you desire one result, use one of

```
.First()
.FirstOrDefault()
.Single()
.SingleOrDefault()
```

on the query, with the difference being your expectation for the result. If more than one item can be present but you're only interested in the first of them, go with `First()`. If only one item *should* match and it's an error if there are more, go with `Single()`. If, in either scenario, it's possible for there to be *no* matches, use the appropriate `*OrDefault()` version.

```
var row = tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData().
               Cast<DataRow>()
               .Where(cName => cName[0].ToString() == txtClientName.Text)
               .FirstOrDefault(); 

if (row != null)
{
     // extract value
}
```

Comment: For future readers.  I ~~think~~ there was a missing ".Rows" (after the .GetData().    Example : MyDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var a = Convert.ToInt16(tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData().Cast<DataRow>().First(r => r[0].ToString() == txtClientName.Text)[1]);
```

But be warned it will throw an exception if there is no match. If that's a possibility, you should do this:

```
var a = tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData().Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r[0].ToString() == txtClientName.Text);
var b = (a != null)?Convert.ToInt16(a[1]):0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use the cast method you should also use the field method.

```
var a = tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData().Cast<DataRow>().Where(t => t.Field<string>(0) == txtClientName.Text).ToList();
```

ToList() added if you want to access via index

If you only need the first match you can replace where with First/FirstOrDefault depending on how you want null handled

```
var a = tableClientTableAdapter1.GetData().Cast<DataRow>().First(t => t.Field<string>(0) == txtClientName.Text);
```

Comment: .ToList() is an evil crutch. The sooner people learn how to avoid it, the better.